# Conditional html is activated before login attempt

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter 2.1. I have the following in my login view:

```
<? if($message == TRUE): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>Login</strong> failed!.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The idea being that this would only be visible if the login attempt fails. However I am noticing that it becomes active the first time the login page is activated. my login controller has the following index function

```
if(!$this->is_logged_in()){
        $this->load->view('login', array('message' => FALSE));
    }
    else{
        redirect('site');
```

I cleared the browser cache so I don't think its a retained cookie.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: You could make it into a type check. `$message === true`. Do a `var_dump($message)` on the message variable to see what value it is being set to.

Comment: I did and the value is correctly set in the view

Comment: 1) do you have an `<?php endif; ?>` in the view? 2) What do you mean by "first time the login page is activated"? Do you mean visit the page? Or is it ajax or something?

Comment: Storm drain you are correct , The server I was working on was not using short tag syntax, so it wasn't recognizing the condition, I changed the syntax and its working now .

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Feel free to delete the question since you have the answer and it can't really help anyone else out.

Comment: @stormdrain Please include your answer below so this may help others with the same weirdness in the future. user61629 can accept it after 6 hours.

Comment: @JohnP Sorry, I flagged the question as the answer seems unrelated and is so localized it's unlikely to ever be helpful to anyone else. I also didn't give a correct answer; OP saw the full tags I used and tried that. If the question should stay and be answered, OP should answer it since they found the solution.